# Horizontal scrolling of a div using mouse and touch

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a `white-space: nowrap;` div with `overflow: hidden;`. Its content is, of course, much longer than the div is, and needs to be scrolled to get revealed.

I was using [this](https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll) library, but it does not work for mobile devices with touch input. Do you know any alternative or ways to implement this feature?

Comment: Take a look to hammer.js - http://hammerjs.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

Finally, my wish is fullfilled. Here I modified dragscroll.js library to enable touch support.

```js
/* Modified dragscroll.js by Undust4able */

(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['exports'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        factory(exports);
    } else {
        factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
    }
}(this, function (exports) {
    var _window = window;
    var _document = document;
 
    var mousemove = 'mousemove';
    var mouseup = 'mouseup';
    var mousedown = 'mousedown';
 
 var touchmove = 'touchmove';
    var touchup = 'touchend';
    var touchdown = 'touchstart';
 
    var EventListener = 'EventListener';
    var addEventListener = 'add'+EventListener;
    var removeEventListener = 'remove'+EventListener;

    var dragged = [];
    var reset = function(i, el) {
        for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
            el = dragged[i++];
            el = el.container || el;
            el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
            _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
            _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
   
    el[removeEventListener](touchdown, el.td, 0);
            _window[removeEventListener](touchup, el.tu, 0);
            _window[removeEventListener](touchmove, el.tm, 0);
        }

        // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
        dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('dragscroll'));
        for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
            (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont){
                (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
                    mousedown,
                    cont.md = function(e) {
                        if (!el.hasAttribute('nochilddrag') ||
                            _document.elementFromPoint(
                                e.pageX, e.pageY
                            ) == cont
                        ) {
                            pushed = 1;
                            lastClientX = e.clientX;
                            lastClientY = e.clientY;

                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }, 0
                );
    (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
                    touchdown,
                    cont.td = function(e) {
                        if (!el.hasAttribute('nochilddrag') ||
                            _document.elementFromPoint(
                                e.pageX, e.pageY
                            ) == cont
                        ) {
                            pushed = 1;
                            e.preventDefault();

       e = e.targetTouches[0];
                            lastClientX = e.clientX;
                            lastClientY = e.clientY;
                            
                        }
                    }, 0
                );
                _window[addEventListener](
                    mouseup, cont.mu = function() {pushed = 0;}, 0
                );
    _window[addEventListener](
                    touchup, cont.tu = function() {pushed = 0;}, 0
                );
                _window[addEventListener](
                    mousemove,
                    cont.mm = function(e) {
                        if (pushed) {
                             (scroller = el.scroller||el).scrollLeft -=
                                 (- lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX));
                             scroller.scrollTop -=
                                 (- lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY));
                        }
                    }, 0
                );
    _window[addEventListener](
                    touchmove,
                    cont.tm = function(e) {
                        if (pushed) {
       e = e.targetTouches[0];
                             (scroller = el.scroller||el).scrollLeft -=
                                 (- lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX));
                             scroller.scrollTop -=
                                 (- lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY));
                        }
      
                    }, 0
                );
             })(dragged[i++]);
        }
    }

      
    if (_document.readyState == 'complete') {
        reset();
    } else {
        _window[addEventListener]('load', reset, 0);
    }

    exports.reset = reset;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a container div with `overflow-y: hidden;overflow-x: scroll;` and set it to whatever pre-determined height you want.

Then have your inner div that will house the content set to `position:absolute;` and set its width to whatever size you need the accommodate your content.

The content will scroll with the mouse and by touch.

Sounds kinda like you're going for a netflix style side scroller - check out this codepen I've done up that shows what I was just talking about.

http://codepen.io/hoonin_hooligan/pen/aZBxRG

Comment: Nope. Content only scrolls with a bar.

Comment: Perhaps i mis-understood the original question. Do you mean that you don't want the content available at all to be scrolled until it's touched or moused over?

Comment: No, I want the content to be scrollable by mouse/touch but without a scrollbar visible.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha! Haven't come across anything that would help you out then, sorry man!